# Is there any way to install Ubuntu 18.04 on RAID0?

Tags: 18.04, raid

I see tutorials on how to install server with RAID, but not a desktop OS. Why not? What is the best work around?

Comment: You haven't said what type of RAID.  If hardware raid - you just install normally. If software raid - the documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID says "*If you're building a desktop then you need the "Alternate" install ISO for Ubuntu.*" so why not just follow the link (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)  note: on second link you'll have to go to "Alternate Installations" section as stated in first link.

Comment: *Why not* Because there is little benefit doing so. Twice as likely to break than a single disk set up, and pretty much pointless with the SSDs.

Comment: Video editing. I have archive storage for anything I need to keep long term, but while working or recording, RAID0 SSDs are awesome. Plus two nvme 500gb SSDs are about the same price as one 1TB SSD, so at that point, "why not" seems like a very valid question. I don't care if anything goes wrong with my disk, that risk calculation is entirely mine. I just want speed, and I should have the option to do so. Or RAID1 if that's what I need. Or RAID5 if that's what I need. There is a LOT of benefit to do so on a desktop OS and you don't know my use case.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't said what type of RAID.

If hardware raid - you just install normally.

If software raid - the documentation

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID states

> "If you're building a desktop then you need the "Alternate" install
>   ISO for Ubuntu."

It provides a link to

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

where you'll have to follow the "*Alternate Installations*" section as stated in first link.  The prime difference is the media used, or as stated in the documentation

> "The Alternate CD allows more advanced installation options which are
>   not available with the standard LiveCD."

Comment: This page was last edited 3 years ago, is it still valid?

Comment: I don't see an Alternate CD iso until I go all the way back to 12.04. http://isos.ubuntu.mirror.constant.com/