# How to setup a RAID

Tags: raid

I have four 2Tb HDDS, with 2 installed right now. Ubuntu sees both drives, but did not configure them into a RAID. How do I set this up?
[HDDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42d2e.png)

Comment: I don't know much about RAID, but this might be a duplicate of [Is there any way to install Ubuntu 18.04 on RAID0?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1071861/301745)

Comment: Are you installing Ubuntu as a desktop?  If so you'll need the alternate install ISO.  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID  In any case, your question is too vague.